# Using indexing a forEach function when not all array elements will be processed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, indexing, foreach

I have a forEach function in my node.js server, below:

```
    fruits.forEach(function(fruit, index, fruits){

      function ONE (response){

      function TWO (response){

      function THREE (response){

      if (index === fruits.length){
      DoAnotherFunction();
               }
            })
         })
      })
    })
```

I need the DoAnotherFunction only to be invoked when each 'fruit' in the fruits array has been processed.

However the problem is that only some fruits will go through functions ONE, TWO and THRE, others may only go through ONE and TWO, and others may not go through any (due to the different operations in the functions)

How can I ensure DoAnotherFunction is only called once the forEach has (or tried too) process each of the fruits through the ONE, TWO and THREE?

Comment: Have you tried to run this code? You could always keep track of when the functions are run, and if that condition is met, run `DoAnotherFunction`

Comment: I have run this code. Could you explain that answer?

Comment: `index` will never be equal to `fruits.length` in `forEach`.

Comment: Yep my error when typing on this site, the code is actually fruits.length - 1

Comment: You're in the loop. I don't know what conditions fruit will trigger each function, but -- set a variable, say var x = 0;. ONE() is run, increment x. x is now 1. If x == 1, TWO(), incremement x to 2 to show that TWO() has been run. Etc etc, then if (x === 3) { dootherfunction()

Comment: @SterlingArcher this solution won't allow me to invade the DoAnotherFunction when ALL the fruits are done, because some won't get the TWO and therefore won't increment?

Answer (score 1):

Your question should be edited to a normal question that everybody can understand. But from what I can gather your looking for something like this:

http://npmjs.org/package/async

```
var async = require('async');

async.each(fruits, function(item, callback) {

  // do whatever with your items
  if (item.id == 1) {

     // long hand
     whatever_one(function(err) {
       if (err) {
         callback(err);
       } else {
         callback();
       }
     });
  } else if (item.id > 2) {

     // short hand
     whatever_two(function(err) {
       if (err) return callback(err);
       callback();
     });
  }

}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    // err handling
  } else {
    DoAnotherFunction();
  }
});
```

What does this do? We use async to control our function callings.

1) For each `fruit` in `fruits` we do `function(item, callback) {}`.

2) After we do `whatever` with fruit we call `callback`.

3) When all fruit items have called callback we do `DoAnotherFunction();`

Answer (score 0):

Like Ferry, I'd use the excellent async library mentioned.

Here's the code (remember to `npm install async`):

```js
var async = require('async');

// Define some fruits to process.
var fruits = [
    {name: "Banana", doesOne: true, doesTwo: true, doesThree: true},
    {name: "Orange", doesOne: false, doesTwo: true, doesThree: true},
    {name: "Apple", doesOne: false, doesTwo: false, doesThree: false},
    {name: "Grape", doesOne: false, doesTwo: true, doesThree: false}
];

// The thing you want to do (asynchronously) ...
var doItem = function (item, index, action, callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Performed async action", action, "on item", index, item.name);
        callback();
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000));
};

// Determine the calls needed.
var queue = [];
fruits.forEach(function (item, index) {
    if (item.doesOne) {
        queue.push(function (callback) {
            doItem(item, index, 1, callback);
        });
    }
    if (item.doesTwo) {
        queue.push(function (callback) {
            doItem(item, index, 2, callback);
        });
    }
    if (item.doesThree) {
        queue.push(function (callback) {
            doItem(item, index, 3, callback);
        });
    }
});

// Process them.
async.parallel(queue, function () {
    console.log("Done", queue.length);
});

console.log("Started.");
```

The code above could be made more compact, but is verbose for clarity. In essence it:

1. Sets up some sample (fruit) data, with flags for each of the three actions possible.
2. Defines a function that can perform those actions when passed the details. This function also gets a callback to advise when it is done (and I've simulated a smallish random run-time delay for each action).
3. Builds an array of all the actions needed for all fruits and all flags they have set. These actions consist of a anonymous functions which call the action function just defined and then via the callback chaining they advise when they are done. This is pushing calls not results.
4. Ask the *async* module to execute them in parallel. When all of them have sent their callbacks, the async library issues the final advisory.

The end output is similar to this:

```
Started.
Performed async action 2 on item 1 Orange
Performed async action 3 on item 0 Banana
Performed async action 2 on item 0 Banana
Performed async action 3 on item 1 Orange
Performed async action 1 on item 0 Banana
Performed async action 2 on item 3 Grape
Done 6
```

*EDIT:*
Note that I assumed asynchronous as it's Node and you don't usually want blocking calls. If sync is fine, probably all you need to look at is the `forEach` loop, and don't bother queueing but just call straight away instead.